# Is it ok if a worker thread that pulls from a BlockingQueue never exits in android?

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I have a thread which basically looks like this:

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException {
   while(true) {
         String curUrl = taskQueue.take();
         ...
   }
}
```

I know I can change `true` to a volatile variable, and set it to false when I no longer need it, but it is used throughout my application, so its difficult to tell when it is no longer needed.

I am wondering if having an infinite loop will have a visible effect on the performance of the rest of the android VM, if its left in a blocked state even when my app is not running.

EDIT 1: The code that starts the thread will only start it if its not already running.

Comment: If you keep starting and stopping your app, do these things keep accumulating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the taskQueue is a blocking queue, no.  Leaving this thread running throughout the application's life will not cause any noticeable effect.

If TaskQueue wasn't a blocking then it would.  Your application will consume a near a whole core of processing power looping as fast as it can.

A blocking queue will cause a thread invoking method 'take' to halt until there is some result available to return.  A non-blocking queue will return null or throw an exception.

Comment: As the `take()` method is defined in the `BlockingQueue` interface and not in `Queue`, I think we can safely assume the queue is a blocking one.

Answer (score 1):

Android will terminate your application's process when it isn't being used, and that will include terminating your waiting thread, so in general it won't hang around for long after users switch away to other tasks.  I wouldn't worry about it, if it's difficult to know when it won't be needed again.